# How to display 1000 separator in C# Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

When working with big numbers, especially `long`, it's a must to display them with 1000 separators.

Is there a way to display those separators?

Inside the watch window?

[image: Watch window example]

When hovering over a variable?

[image: Hovering example]

Comment: I don't believe you can.

Comment: I have taken the freedom and opened [VS Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/723761/add-debugger-format-specifier-to-show-numbers-with.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the other answers, it's not directly possible. So until the [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/723761/add-debugger-format-specifier-to-show-numbers-with.html) lands in Visual Studio, you need to manually do it. So to sum up, you can:

- use `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` to change the way members of an object are shown (see [this blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/customize-object-displays-in-the-visual-studio-debugger-your-way/?WT.mc_id=vstoolbox-c9-niner))
- add a new variable with the string representation in your code (this is quite dirty as you'll want to remove it once you're done debugging)
- format the data in the `Watch` window (so your first need to add your data in the watch window, and it won't work when you hover over your data). Eg

```cs
// For a long variable
myLong.ToString("N0")
// For a long array variable (that might slow VSNet down if you have tons of rows)
myLongArray.Select(l => l.ToString("N0"))
```

Answer (score 4):

it's technically possible but not straightforward.  Your easiest way would be to create a 2nd formatted variable and watch that instead.

The only way i know of to do this in the watch window is you can actually "watch" an expression by typing it in the watch window as an edit to the variable.  The expression would append a formatted toString.  This doesn't seem to work with arrays though.

Say however you had a variable "total".  your watch would say total and you would double click on it and edit it to say total.ToString("C");

I hope this helps.

Comment: One technical way could be using the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute as described in [this blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/customize-object-displays-in-the-visual-studio-debugger-your-way/?WT.mc_id=vstoolbox-c9-niner). But this only really works/makes sense if you want to improve the displaying of members for an object.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a new array(stringNumbers), which is having the thousand separator and use it in the watch window for your debugging purpose. After you are done with debugging, you can remove this array.

```
int[] numbers = { 100000, 300000 };
string[] stringNumbers = numbers.Select(n => n.ToString("N")).ToArray();
```

You can watch stringNumbers here in the watch window.

Comment: Thanks, but you don't actually need to create a new array in the code. Just write numbers.Select(n => n.ToString("N")) straight in the Watch window. This works great, at least for small arrays.